# Adding all the values in a column in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Column called "Salary" in jTable whose data type is set to int which gets its data(*say n number of records*) from a database in MYSQL through connectivity.

I want to add all the salaries present in 'n' number of rows in the column salary and display it as total money spent by the company.

I thought about using `getText(Integer.parseInt());` method to get the values,store it in data type int, sum it up and display it in a jTextField but the number of rows/data records is not fixed.

I've tried the following

```
int total =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                int num = (int) jTable1.getValueAt(i,3); //3rd column, i number of rows
                total = total  +num;
            }
        total1.setText(Integer.toString(total));
```

EDIT: 
error when running the code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1988)
    at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2582)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2718)
    at cart.<init>(cart.java:91)
    at cart$3.run(cart.java:264)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Why don't you show some code for what you're trying to do? Even posting "wrong" code is fine. At least it gives us an idea of what you're thinking and what to fix.

Comment: alright . I tried this

Comment: The index of the third column is 2, not 3. Virtually all indexed data structures are zero indexed, meaning the first index is zero, second is one and so on... Why don't you have another try now.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, you should post your solution as an answer, not edit it into your question.

Comment: cannot answer it for some reason.